# How do I extrude a region in autodesk inventor?

Tags: autodesk-inventor

I'm a beginner at autodesk inventor.
For some instances when I click a region to extrude it doesn't come alone.

The screenshot below illustrates something even stranger.

What should I do to make this not to happen?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a sketch, you cannot have two lines that intersect themselves. You have to split them with the Split tool.

Your bottom line for example, must be divided into 10 parts.

Comment: Just to clarify: this is true only when extruding or doing other specific operations, correct? In general a sketch is valid even if it has intersecting lines?

Comment: To extrude, revolve, sweep... you need a closed profile if you want to create a solid. To create a surface, all profiles can be used.